# How to set local html file to Frame in Gwt

Tags: gwt, frame

```
Frame frame = new Frame("path of the file");
```

For Example:

```
E:\html\file1.html
```

How can I give the specified file path of html file which in my desktop local machine in Gwt Frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can not link to local files in HTML (not by using A HREF, and not in IFrames).
These links will be blocked by the browser.

Since this does not work in HTML, by extension it will also not work in GWT.

Comment: Actually, you can link to local files.`<iframe src="file://C:/iframe_content.html"</iframe>` is OK but only if host document is your local file too ;) When linking from remote file you'll get `Not allowed to load local resource` error.